# Boolean modifier creates mesh hole that Rigid Body Sim ignores

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to model a pool table where the balls would fall into holes during play.  If I create the Passive table object with boolean modifiers Difference with cylinder the RB-active spheres (balls) do not fall through the holes, whereas if I Apply the boolean, all's well.

[image]

Because I may want to resize or move the holes, I don't want to Apply the boolean cylinder holes.

Is there a way to coax the boolean to work with Rigid Body World or is this some limitation ?

Example: [image]

Comment: Edited my answer to a method that supports moving boolean sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your mesh with the boolean modifier, change the collision source to final.

[image: rigidbody source]

If your boolean source changes, you will need to set the collision source to final every frame, I did that with python, the only way i managed to:

```
import bpy

# every frame change, this function is called.
def fixRB(scene):
    ob = bpy.data.objects.get("Cube.001")
    ob.rigid_body.mesh_source = 'FINAL'

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(fixRB)
```

Result:

[image: result]

When you animate your boolean source, you will see all spheres behave incorrectly:

[image: glitch]

A workaround i found is to let all boolean modifiers disabled for the first two frames, then enable them after, you will need to remove those first frames from your animation after rendering.

[image: glitch workaround result]

**Edit:**

If you don't deactivate boolean modifiers for the first two frames, blender will crash when rendering.

[image: keyframed boolean viewport display]
[image: boolean modifier keyframes]

I doesn't even need to be deactivated in render, but for some reason the viewport option affects the render:

[image: Render with booleans enabled at the start]

Comment: Love your "move the hole" animation effect!  Like the tax man moving the hole to empty my bank account of play marbles, LOL.