# Objects falling through an animated hole

Tags: animation, modifiers, physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I have this little project going on, where I have a plane with objects standing on them. The plane has a hole, and I want to animate the hole around so that the objects standing on the plane just fall through it. I hope it makes sense xD

I tried animating the hole with a single bone, and then animating the hole as a shape keys, but in both scenarios I didn't get the objects to fall through the hole when it was animated. If it's not animated it just works.

Do you have any idea how could I approach it?
I attached the project file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V_mO4v7DGXPm3cpH-5Xq5LHc5F09kdN9/view?usp=share_link

This is a reference to what I'd like to create (much more simple, and with less objects though)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZWoB-MxB6w&ab_channel=ZackScottGames

[image]

Comment: Hello, the title is not very explicit, it's about balls falling through an animated hole, something like that, no? Not sure why you're talking about the boolean?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work but you could cheat and the object with the hole could be invisible so that you simply move it in the 3D space (no armature or shapekey)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boolean modifier creates mesh hole that Rigid Body Sim ignores](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261418/boolean-modifier-creates-mesh-hole-that-rigid-body-sim-ignores)

Comment: i just tried that solution in Blender 3.6 - and it worked - so i assume it works in your version as well. You have to copy the script and run it once before starting the animation. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAEEj.gif

Comment: Thank you Chris! That may be the solution I was looking for! As I have never used python scripts in Blender (my bad), I guess my next question is how do I use the script? Do I simply paste it in a new script editor page within Blender?

Comment: I love the use of Hole.io gameplay as your example.  I've wasted many hours devouring buildings, farms, and such in this game.